# how to add 2 static blocks to a category page

Tags: category, static-block

i have a staic block called "sub categories" and i have this set to all my parent categories so when you click on them it shows the sub categories. However i also want to add another static block to the parent category to show the products that are on sale. I already have the On_sale static block created and correctly coded i just dont know how to add it to the parent category as there is only 1 drop down box for the static blocks.

Question: how to add a second static block on a category page?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a static block into a static block:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="your_second_block_id"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to do this with xml on "your cat" -> "custom design" -> "custom layout update":

```
<reference name="content">
     <block type="cms/block" name="your_block_name" as="your_block_alias">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>your_block_identifier</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

by adding before="other_block_alias" or after="other_block_alias" attribute to block-tag you should also be able to set position. If you use "-" as value for that, it means first or last of all blocks in that reference.